# How to remove GoforFiles from Wine?

Tags: wine

GoforFiles is some kind of annoying search engine addition to Windows which likes to install itself.

I searched the internet and there are some howto's for windows but it sits in my Wine on Ubuntu 12.04, and I don't have IE installed so I can't follow those manuals.

I attempted to remove it, but it doesn't want to go.

It has an "Uninstall" option in the Wine Start menu but it doesn't work. How can I fully remove it ?

Comment: Have you tried wine's "uninstall applications" app? You should find it by searching for "wine" in the Dash. The name might differ, my system language is German.

Comment: @speter Is that different from the one the OP refers to in the last line?

Comment: It is similar to Windows' "Software" app in the system settings, while he has tried to use the application's own uninstaller.